# How does AsRef work with str?

Tags: rust

I want to write a trait which could take a string slice directly:

```
use std::path::Path;

trait Trait1 {}

impl Trait1 for str {}
// impl<'a> Trait1 for &'a str {}

fn run<T: Trait1>(_: T) {}
fn run1<T: AsRef<Path>>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    // E0277: the trait bound `&str: Trait1` is not satisfied
    // run::<&str>("sf");
    run1::<&str>("sf");
}
```

Note that

```
run::<&str>("sf");
```

won't compile unless `Trait1` is also implemented for `&str`. However, `AsRef` works despite also [being implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#2161-2165) for `str` only. Is there anything special about AsRef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for `AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), you will see that it lists the following implementation:

```
impl<'a, T, U> AsRef<U> for &'a T where T: AsRef<U> + ?Sized, U: ?Sized
```

That is, `str` implementing `AsRef<Path>` means that `&str` *also* implements `AsRef<Path>`.